# Declaring an empty pattern matching function

Tags: scala

How do I declare an empty/case-less pattern matching function to satisfy a type definition? I'm happy with the function just throwing a runtime exception if it's ever called.

I'm working through the [Scala tutorial for Java programmers](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-for-java-programmers.html), in which I have a working function that performs variable substitution on a mathematic expression presented as a tree given a `String => Int` map. I want to call the same code path even when no variables should exist (in this case after taking a derivative of the expression), but I can't find a concise way to satisfy the type requirements. Here's the full code I have that works but feels wrong:

```scala
abstract class Tree

case class Sum(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree
case class Var(n: String) extends Tree
case class Const(v: Int) extends Tree

object CalculatorPatternsPrime {
  def eval(tree: Tree, env: String => Int): Int = tree match {
    case Sum(l, r) => eval(l, env) + eval(r, env)
    case Var(n) => env(n)
    case Const(v) => v
  }

  def eval(tree: Tree): Int = eval(tree, { case "ignore" => -1 })

  def derive(tree: Tree, v: String): Tree = tree match {
    case Sum(l, r) => Sum(derive(l, v), derive(r, v))
    case Var(n) if (n == v) => Const(1)
    case _ => Const(0)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env: String => Int = { case "x" => 5 case "y" => 7 }
    val tree = Sum(
      Sum(Const(7), Var("y")),
      Sum(Var("x"), Var("x"))
    )
    println(eval(tree, env))
    println(derive(tree, "x"))
    println(eval(derive(tree, "x")))
  }
}
```

As you can see I have a dummy `{ case "ignore" => -1 }` to make the type system happy, and the code works fine but I feel like there must be a better way to do this. Here are two alternatives I've considered:

1. Just writing out a full method body to `eval(tree: Tree)` instead of trying to call `eval(tree: Tree, env: String => Int)` but this duplicates the code handling the `Sum` and `Const` cases.
2. Making `env` an optional/union type and letting it throw an NPE.

What is the idiomatic approach here?

Comment: I'd remove the 2nd `eval()` and just give `env` the default value of `_ => -1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this:

First, as jwvh noted, you can eliminate the single-argument `eval` by using a default argument for the second parameter in the two-argument `eval`.

The question then arises, what should that default argument be?

`env` is a `String => Int`, which is shorthand for `Function1[-A, +R]`: contravariant in the argument type and covariant in the result type.  For our purposes, this means that any function which accepts a supertype of `String` (including `String`) and results in a subtype of `Int` (including `Int`) will work.

Since you've said you're OK with throwing, this is a reasonable default function:

```
{ a: Any => throw new AssertionError(s"shouldn't have looked up $a in the environment") }
```

Assuming that some other component of the system is ensuring that if there's a `Var` expression in the tree passed to `eval`, there's always an appropriate entry in the environment, this might be the most honest thing to do: something important in your system isn't maintaining an invariant, so trying to reason about it in your system might just make things worse.

That function works because it has the type `Any => Nothing`, which is a subtype of `String => Int`: you can pass it a `String` (`String` is a subtype of `Any`) and it will never have a result that's not an `Int` or a subtype of an `Int` (it doesn't have a result).

As an alternative, you could also use `PartialFunction.empty` as a default, which will throw a `MatchError` if it's ever called.  This fits using a partial function literal (which is what a bare `{ case... }` block is).

So I would have either (both have `type Env = String => Int`)

```
val emptyEnv: Env = { a: Any => throw new AssertionError(s"shouldn't have looked up $a in the environment") }
```

or

```
val emptyEnv: Env = PartialFunction.empty
```

And then define `eval` as:

```
def eval(tree: Tree, env: Env = emptyEnv): Int
```

As a side note, I would strongly recommend making `Tree` `sealed`:

```
sealed abstract class Tree
```

Which limits where classes extending `Tree` can be defined and gives you a stronger guarantee that invariants about `Tree`s are enforced.

Comment: Thank you for sharing these examples!